# Transform usage - How to push event for all specific terms even if one of them is missing

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have a scenario. I have a transform created that groups all events of each day from the source index into 3 different status - Completed, Terminated and Retry. For example, if for 25th Apr 2021 we have Completed - 3, Terminated - 5 and Retry - 1, then destination index has 3 records for 25th Apr as shown below.

```
{"keyword": "Completed","Count": 3, "Per day": "2021-04-25T00:00:00.000Z"}
{"keyword": "Terminated","Count": 5, "Per day": "2021-04-25T00:00:00.000Z"}
{"keyword": "Retry","Count": 1, "Per day": "2021-04-25T00:00:00.000Z"}
```

This is all working as expected. Now, if there is no Retry events for 26th Apr, transform has following in destination index which is again as expected.

```
{"keyword": "Completed","Count": 3, "Per day": "2021-04-26T00:00:00.000Z"}
{"keyword": "Terminated","Count": 5, "Per day": "2021-04-26T00:00:00.000Z"}
```

But the problem is I need to push the data from destination index to another output(Kafka, in my case) for all the 3 cases, including one for the missing Retry. So, effectively I want to push to Kafka 3 events as shown below(including one for Retry with count as 0) instead of 2

```
{"keyword": "Completed","Count": 3, "Per day": "2021-04-26T00:00:00.000Z"}
{"keyword": "Terminated","Count": 5, "Per day": "2021-04-26T00:00:00.000Z"}
{"keyword": "Retry","Count": 0, "Per day": "2021-04-26T00:00:00.000Z"}
```

**Not sure how this can be achieved. Any suggestions/inputs here will be very helpful.**

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is still [some known issues](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/55102) around usage of missing_bucket even with version 7.10 and greater. I have gone with a different approach for my requirement.
I am using terms filter to check for specific keywords so that I can get a 0 count in case there are no events that fall into the bucket

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want to add the `missing_bucket` setting. It requires you to be on version 7.10 or greater, and is described in the forums at https://discuss.elastic.co/t/transform-sum-doesnt-add-up/256622/5

As mentioned in that thread, the official docs cover this at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html#_missing_bucket

Comment: I guess there is still some known issues around usage of missing_bucket even with version 7.10 and greater. I have gone with a different approach for my requirement. I am using terms filter to check for specific keywords so that I can get a 0 count in case there are no events that fall into the bucket